# PgQuery gem not working after upgrade rails version from 5.1.3 to 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, pg-query

Recently I updated my rails version from 5.1.3 to 5.2.3.
I deleted my Gemfile.lock file & run bundle install && bundle update command.
Now everything is working fine except pg_query. It shows me

> undefined method `first' for #PgQuery::ParseResult:0x00007f52e47f69b0

**pg_query (2.1.0)** this is my current pg_query version in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

I get back to my previous version of pg_query(1.1.0) & now everything is working as expected.